# Show 15 results only

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble with my members list. It shows EVERY username but i would like it to show only 15 per row.

The code:

```
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="23%"><em><strong>Username</strong></em></td>
  </tr>
  <?
  $sql = mysql_query("select * from usr_users");
  while($m = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
  { ?>
  <tr>
<td width="23%"><div style="float: left;" onMouseover="ddrivetip('<em><? echo("$m[username]");?></em> <br /> <b>Rank:</b> <? echo("$m[rankerslevel]");?><br /> <b>Bits:</b> <? echo("$m[credits]");?><br /> <b>Score:</b> <? echo("$m[points]");?><br /> <b>Mood:</b> <? echo("$m[usrstatus]");?><br /> <b>ID:</b> <? echo("$m[id]");?><br /> <b>Sex:</b> <? echo("$m[sexmalefemale]");?><br /> <b>Country:</b> <? echo("$m[countrywhere]");?><br />','white', 100)";
     onMouseout="hideddrivetip()"><img src="/bolt.png" alt="member_icon"/> <a href="memb.php?user=<? echo("$m[username]");?>"><font color="<? echo("$m[usercolour]");?>"><? echo("$m[username]");?></font></a></td></div>
    <? } ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post the code you are having difficulty with. It isn't really possible for us to determine how you're doing that from the image alone.

Comment: Can you show some of the code you are using now? Hard to fix what I can't see.

Comment: btw, it's considered good practise to use full PHP tags `<?php` instead of `<?`. Also, don't forget to escape your output correctly. Aslo, the `font` tag is deprecated, use CSS to style elements.

Answer (score 2):

Use `LIMIT` clause. Here is usage:

```
LIMIT [offset,] rows
```

Examples:

```
SELECT * from usr_users LIMIT 0, 10
```

This query will retrieve 1-10 rows (from 0 to 10).

```
SELECT * from usr_users LIMIT 10, 10
```

This query will retrieve 11-19 rows.

If you want to get row with specific ids use `IN` statement:

```
SELECT * from usr_users WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

Also read this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

If you want to learn how to make pagination, look at this topic: http://www.codediesel.com/php/simple-pagination-in-php/

Answer (score 1):

the simpliest soultion would be:

```
SELECT * FROM usr_users LIMIT 15
```

Answer (score 0):

use mysql limit

```
select * from usr_users order by createddate desc LIMIT 0, 15
```

assuming you have a column called createddate on which you are doing an order by.

This will get you the last 15 users created.

You can get the total number of records and divide it by the "items to be displayed " to get the number of paging elements.

http://www.dharshin.com/2007/09/paging-results-with-php-and-mysql-part.html

Comment: That limit shows 15 members but I need numbers; 1, 2, 3 etc to see the rest of the members.

Comment: @NicholasPandie The link i added in my answer gives you a better idea.

Comment: Most people do a `COUNT(*)` query first to get the number of the rows. The first parameter in the LIMIT clause is the offset start position, so to get the second page, you would do `LIMIT 15, 15`, which gets results 16 through 30, since the first record is offset 0.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have an 'id' column - and it is set as Auto_Increment (as-well as an INT)

```
SELECT * FROM usr_users ORDER BY -id LIMIT 15
```

This will grab the 15 most latest users, and show them in order.